# How to compare a var with an integer (0) in Django Template?

Tags: html, django, django-models, django-templates

I cannot figure this one out and it is driving me nuts! Seems so simple but I must be missing something. I am trying to compare a count (integer) with 0, if the value of the count is 0 then print a message using noty. Here is my code:

```
var count = 0;
{% for inf in prospect.prospect_industries.all %}
    {% if inf.is_interested %}
        count = count + 1;
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

displayNotification(count + " " + zero); //I see 0 0 in the message
{% if count == 0 %}
    displayNotification("Count is 0!!!!");
{% endif %}
```

What am I missing? I tried using "0" |add:0 to convert the count variable but nothing works, it just never goes inside the if checking if count == 0.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count` is a Javascript variable in your code, so use a Javascript `if` statement:

```
if (count === 0) {
    displayNotification("Count is 0!!!!");
}
```

You can only use `{% if %}` with variables passed from your views to your template context (or ones available in all templates like `user` etc.).

Comment: Wow. I cannot believe I didn't notice that. I guess I've been looking at this code for far too long today. Thank you!

Comment: @user2573690 haha, yeah, I know that feeling for sure. We have all been there - or at least I have...